# podman container crashes on running ENTRYPOINT script

Tags: build, haproxy, podman

I want to build haproxy based on [these instructions](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/how-to-install-haproxy-rhel/) for rhel8 inside a podman (almalinux:8) container.

running a container from an image built like this

```bash
FROM almalinux:8

COPY make_ha_proxy.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["make_ha_proxy.sh"]
```

crashes on building hopraxy though.

When I do

```
podman run -tdi --rm --name test -v ./return:/tmp/binary_return almalinux:8
podman cp make_ha_proxy.sh test:/usr/local/bin
podman exec -it test2 bash /usr/local/bin/make_ha_proxy.sh
```

instead, I can collect my binary from the `./return` directory afterwards, so my script in general seems to work.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

HAPROXY_MINOR='2.8.2'
HAPROXY_MAJOR='2.8'
LUA_VERSION='5.4.6'
RETURN_DIR='/tmp/binary_return/'

# installing dependencies
dnf update -y
dnf install -y gcc openssl-devel readline-devel systemd-devel make pcre-devel file

# get and build lua
mkdir -p /opt/lua && cd /opt/lua || exit

curl https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-${LUA_VERSION}.tar.gz > lua-${LUA_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar xvf lua-${LUA_VERSION}.tar.gz && cd lua-${LUA_VERSION} || exit
make INSTALL_TOP=/opt/lua-${LUA_VERSION} linux install

lua_rc=$?
if [ ${lua_rc} != 0 ] ; then
   echo "building lua failed !" ; exit 1
fi

# get and build ha_proxy
mkdir -p /opt/haproxy && cd /opt/haproxy || exit
curl http://www.haproxy.org/download/${HAPROXY_MAJOR}/src/haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}.tar.gz > haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}.tar.gz
curl http://www.haproxy.org/download/${HAPROXY_MAJOR}/src/haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}.tar.gz.sha256 > haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}.tar.gz.sha256

cd /opt/haproxy && tar xvf haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}.tar.gz
cd /opt/haproxy/haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR} || exit
make USE_NS=1 \
    USE_TFO=1 \
    USE_OPENSSL=1 \
    USE_ZLIB=1 \
    USE_LUA=1 \
    USE_PCRE=1 \
    USE_SYSTEMD=1 \
    USE_LIBCRYPT=1 \
    USE_THREAD=1 \
    TARGET=linux-glibc \
    LUA_INC=/opt/lua-${LUA_VERSION}/include \
    LUA_LIB=/opt/lua-${LUA_VERSION}/lib

make PREFIX=/opt/haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR} install

# move the build binary to the return directory
if [ ! -d ${RETURN_DIR}  ] ; then
   mkdir -p -- "${RETURN_DIR}"
fi

# copying the created binary to the return directory
if [ $(file -b --mime-type /opt/haproxy/haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}/haproxy | sed 's|/.*||') == application ] ; then
   cp /opt/haproxy/haproxy-${HAPROXY_MINOR}/haproxy "${RETURN_DIR}"/
else
   exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

any hint, what might be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to a tip of my colleague it seems the `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile needs the entire path, not just the name of the script

```bash
FROM almalinux:8

COPY make_ha_proxy.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/make_ha_proxy.sh"]
```